# How to create a new tuple type from an old one and a type in boost?

Tags: c++, boost, tuples

I have a tuple type. I want to add a element type in it to get a new tuple type. I can do it like

```
decltype tuple_cat(MyTuple, std::tuple<MyType>())
```

However, I don't find `tuple_cat` in `boost::tuple`, how to do it in boost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want all this in compile time.

Here is the general explanation: concatening tuples is similar to concatening lists or arrays, is that the algorithm is the same. Here, given tuples `a` and `b`, I choosed to move the last element of `a` to the beginning of `b`, and repeat until `a` is empty.

First: base structures. The following structure keeps a parameter pack. It can be anything, for example a tuple:

```
template<typename... T>
struct pack
{
    static const unsigned int size = sizeof...(T);
};
```

Note that the size of the pack is stored inside it. It is not mandatory, but it is convenient for the explanation. Boost uses the struct `boost::tuples::length<T>::value` (which is more verbose).

To access an element at i-th position, we use a structure similar to `boost::tuples::element<n, T>`:

```
// Get i-th element of parameter pack
// AKA 'implementation'
// Principle: the element i is the first element of the sub-array starting at indice i-1
template<int n, typename F, typename... T>
struct element_at : public element_at<n-1, T...>
{
};

template<typename F, typename... T>
struct element_at<0, F, T...>
{
    typedef F type;
};

// Get i-th element of pack
// AKA 'interface' for the 'pack' structure
template<int n, typename P>
struct element
{
};

template<int n, typename... T>
struct element<n, pack<T...>>
{
    typedef typename element_at<n, T...>::type type;
};
```

Now, we must use a low-level operation which is adding one element to a side of a pack (adding at left or at right). Here adding at left is choosed, but it is not the only choice:

```
// Concat at left (only for structure 'pack')
template<typename a, typename b>
struct tuple_concat_left
{
};

template<typename a, typename... b>
struct tuple_concat_left<a, pack<b...>>
{
    typedef pack<a, b...> type;
};
```

For templates, `a` is not changed, and instead we use an indice to know what element to add. The inheritance define a 'type' typedef which is the concatenation of all indices after `n` and the other tuple (not including `n`, and in order). We just have to concatenate at left the element at indice `n`.

```
// Concat 2 tuples
template<typename a, typename b, int n = 0, bool ok = (n < a::size)>
struct tuple_concat : public tuple_concat<a, b, n+1>
{
    typedef typename tuple_concat_left<
        typename element<n, a>::type,
        typename tuple_concat<a, b, n+1>::type
    >::type type;
};

template<typename a, typename b, int n>
struct tuple_concat<a, b, n, false>
{
    typedef b type;
};
```

And that's it! [Live example here](http://ideone.com/ALUSYa).

Now, for tuple specifics: you noticed I didn't used boost::tuple nor std::tuple. That is because a lot of implementations of boost tuplesdo not have access to variadic templates, so a fixed number of template parameters is used (they default to `boost::tuples::null_type`). Putting this directly with variadic templates is a headache, thus the need to have another abstraction.

I also assumed that you can use C++11 (with the `decltype` in your question). Concatening 2 tuples in C++03 is possible, but more repetitive and boring.

You can convert a `pack` to a tuple really easily: just change the `pack` definition to:

```
template<typename... T>
struct pack
{
    static const unsigned int size = sizeof...(T);
    typedef boost::tuple<T...> to_tuple; // < convert this pack to a boost::tuple
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C++14 offers a library to generate a sequence of integers at compile type. This helps manipulating static sequences like tuples and arrays ([example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)).
An integer sequence can be obtained

```
template<size_t... Ints>
struct integer_sequence {};

template<size_t Size, size_t... Ints>
struct implementation : implementation<Size-1, Size-1, Ints...> {};

template<size_t... Ints>
struct implementation<0, Ints...>
{
    typedef integer_sequence<Ints...> type;
};

template<class... T>
using index_sequence_for = typename implementation<sizeof...(T)>::type;
```

To concat `MyTuple` and `MyType` you can write the simple functions:

```
template<typename X, typename Tuple, size_t... Ints>
auto concat(X x, Tuple t, integer_sequence<Ints...>)
    -> decltype( std::make_tuple(x, std::get<Ints>(t)...) )
{
    return std::make_tuple(x, std::get<Ints>(t)...);
}

template<typename X, typename... T>
std::tuple<X, T...> concat(X x, std::tuple<T...> t)
{
    return concat(x, t, index_sequence_for<T...>());
}

concat(MyType, MyTuple);
```