# Define tuples of numbers in d dimensions and accessing them

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array

I am playing with an idea that might seem contorted, but I like the challenge, although it's just a C++ exercise I've invented.

The task is to store a series of **n** scalars in **d** dimensions. Imagine having a vector, a matrix, or a 3D matrix of **n** doubles, or integers, or whatever, and choosing how many are there at runtime (calculated by hand, nothing fancy).

Let's say for example I'd like a 1D array long `4` of two-doubles (`n == 2`, `d == 1`, at runtime I say I want a storage of `4`):

```
| d0 d1 | d0 d1 | d0 d1 | d0 d1 |
```

Or a 2D `2x4` grid of 3 doubles (`n == 3`, `d == 2`, at runtime I say I want a storage of `2 * 4`):

```
| d0 d1 d2 | d0 d1 d2 | d0 d1 d2 | d0 d1 d2 |
| d0 d1 d2 | d0 d1 d2 | d0 d1 d2 | d0 d1 d2 |
```

How am I accessing for instance the `i, j`-th element of the grid? With an operator, of course... but I'd like to write a **single** operator returning a **tuple of references** to the three doubles.

To give an idea:

```
template <std::size_t n, std::size_t d, typename Number>
class storage
{
public:

    // Magic tricks here?
    auto operator()(std::size_t i_0, ..., std::size_t i_d) -> std::tuple<n std::ref<Number>s>
    {

    }
};
```

The problem is, how can I play some magic template tricks here to define *one* operator that returns a *tuple of homogeneous types*?

I find it particularly difficult to think about how to define that tuple, and of course, the operator that must have exactly **d** parameters.

As for the usage, I’d like to be able to work like this for instance in the 2D example:

```
 // define a matrix of three doubles
 storage<3, 2, double> storageobj(8);

 // get a block, these should be references
 auto block = storageobj(0, 1);
 std::get<0>(block) = -123.456;
```

Please note that the actual implementation of how to access elements in memory is of no concern now to me, but the definition of the return types and how to make the `operator()` are the primary objective of this exercise.

Can some magic TMP help here?

Comment: You can create such a tuple with info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17644256/752976). I'd write it up, but I think someone will be quicker. The operator impl itself is pretty easy then.

Comment: `std::array` might be more appropriate if type are identical.

Comment: So you want a d-dimensional matrix of n-dimensional vectors, but what governs the size of the matrix? Also, this sounds a lot like boost::multi_array.

Comment: I modified the question according to @Quentin's comment. I pass at runtime the length of the storage computing how many blocks I need (rows times columns). And no, I'd like to avoid boost, as long as I can have fun with coding it.

Comment: @senseiwa - sorry but aren't clear to me the dimension involved. And which dimension are known run-time and wich one compile-time (and maybe are, somewhere, template parameters). Can you add some example of intended declaration/initialization and use?

Comment: @max66 Sorry, I forgot the template definition! Now the question has been edited. Basically, at runtime I just need to know how many blocks I need to store, at compile time, the block size and its dimension.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are absolutely right, I wonder though what difference would it make performance-wise to use an array of references with respect to a tuple of references. However, I’d really like to use a tuple just for the fun of it :)

Comment: @senseiwa - just trying to understand... but... it seems to me that only if all sizes are fixed compile time (so `storage<3, 2, 8, double> storageobj;` instead of `storage<3, 2, double> storageobj<3, 2, double> storageobj{8}`) make sense returning a tuple of references because a variation of the run-time value (the length) can cause the relocation of values of the effective data container (a `std::vector`, I suppose) so the references obtained (before) with `operator()` are not valid anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `MultiArray` from [How to allocate & access 3D, 4D, 5D arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33042764/2684539) to have some static size with `std::array`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
class MultiArray
{
public:

    explicit MultiArray(const std::array<std::size_t, Dim>& dimensions) :
        dimensions(dimensions),
        values(computeTotalSize(dimensions))
    {
        assert(!values.empty());
    }

    const T& get(const std::array<std::size_t, Dim>& indexes) const
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }
    T& get(const std::array<std::size_t>& indexes)
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes)];
    }

    std::size_t computeIndex(const std::array<std::size_t, Dim>& indexes) const
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        size_t mul = 1;

        for (size_t i = 0; i != dimensions.size(); ++i) {
            assert(indexes[i] < dimensions[i]);
            index += indexes[i] * mul;
            mul *= dimensions[i];
        }
        assert(index < values.size());
        return index;
    }

    std::array<std::size_t, Dim> computeIndexes(std::size_t index) const
    {
        assert(index < values.size());

        std::array<std::size_t, Dim> res;

        std::size_t mul = values.size();
        for (std::size_t i = dimensions.size(); i != 0; --i) {
            mul /= dimensions[i - 1];
            res[i - 1] = index / mul;
            assert(res[i - 1] < dimensions[i - 1]);
            index -= res[i - 1] * mul;
        }
        return res;
    }

private:
    std::size_t computeTotalSize(const std::array<std::size_t, Dim>& dimensions) const
    {
        std::size_t totalSize = 1;

        for (auto i : dimensions) {
            totalSize *= i;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

private:
    std::array<std::size_t, Dim> dimensions;
    std::vector<T> values;
};
```

Then add layer to adapt it to your interface (`MultiArray` might have been written similar to `storage_impl` to avoid that).

To transform `array<std::size_t, N>` in to `std::size_t, .., std::size_t`, we use `std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, .., N - 1>` to allow variadic expansion. then we just have to transform it to type:

```
template <std::size_t, typename T>
using always_type = T;

template <std::size_t n, typename Seq, typename Number>
class storage_impl;

template <std::size_t n, typename Number, std::size_t ... Is>
class storage_impl<n, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Number>
{
public:
    storage_impl(always_type<Is, std::size_t>... dims) : array{{{dims...}}} ()

    std::array<Number, n>&
    operator()(always_type<Is, std::size_t>... indexes)
    {
        return array.get({{indexes...}});
    }

    const std::array<Number, n>&
    operator()(always_type<Is, std::size_t>... indexes) const
    {
        return array.get({{indexes...}});
    }

private:
    MultiArray<std::array<Number, n>, sizeof...(Is)> array;
};
```

And finally:

```
template <std::size_t n, std::size_t d, typename Number>
using storage = storage_impl<n, std::make_index_sequence<d>, Number>;
```

Usage would be similar to:

```
// define a 2D matrix of three doubles
 storage<3, 2, double> storageobj(2, 4); // matrix 2x4 of std::array<double, 3>

 auto&& block = storageobj(0, 1); // std::array<double, 3>&
 std::get<0>(block) = -123.456;   // or block[0] = -123.456
```